# Nginx - Can I specify rate in limit_req_zone in requests per hour?

Tags: nginx, web-server, rate-limiting

While limiting the number of requests from an IP, I am using

```
limit_req_zone  $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=1r/m;
```

I can specify the rate in **r/m** (requests per minute) or **r/s** (requests per second). Is there a way to specify the rate in  **requests/hour** ?

For example, I want the rate to be 75 requests/hour. So it will be 1.25r/m, but r/m has to be an integer. So, even that way it doesn't work.

Please help me out.

Comment: Have you tried `75r/h`?

Comment: @AlexeyTen Yes, I did. The conf file fails to pass the syntax test. The r/h doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[According to the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html#limit_req_zone) you can specify in requests per second or requests per minute, not requests per hour, so no it's not possible.

```
The rate is specified in requests per second (r/s). If a rate of
less than one request per second is desired, it is specified in
request per minute (r/m). For example, half-request per second
is 30r/m.
```

I suggest you round up or round down, according to your use case. 1r/s is 60 requests per minute, 2r/s is 120 requests per minute.

Answer (score 7):

At some point, I needed the same function to define rate limits per hour, day, week, etc.

I was itchy to build a clone of `ngx_http_limit_req_module` first, but then just integrated the necessary changes to [nginx-mod](https://www.getpagespeed.com/nginx-mod-a-better-faster-nginx-build).

So this works with nginx-mod:

```
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=1r/h; # 1 request per hour
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=1r/d; # 1 request per day
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=1r/w; # 1 request per week
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=1r/M; # 1 request per month
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=1r/Y; # 1 request per year
```